# How to Lock apps using FingerPrint in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Can we lock other apps (eg.Facebook, Twitter) with fingerprint using Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, as you can't handle access over other apps then your own app.

Comment: #onlyonandroid (sorry).